# Pure js arrays merge where elements alternate

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253856/merge-two-arrays-so-that-the-values-alternate) but it is closed, author narrowed it to jQuery, and answers are only for case when two arrays has equal size.

So my question is how to merge two arbitrary arrays where elements alternate? (in answer provide function `m(a,b)` which take two arrays `a` and `b` and return merged array)

Test cases:

```
var as = [1,2,3];
var am = [1,2,3,4,5];
var al = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var b  = ["a","b","c","d","e"];

var m = (a,b) => "...magic_here..."; 

m(as,b); // -> [1,"a",2,"b",3,"c","d","e"] 
m(am,b); // -> [1,"a",2,"b",3,"c",4,"d",5,"e"] 
m(al,b); // -> [1,"a",2,"b",3,"c",4,"d",5,"e",6,7]
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682736/rebuilding-zip-in-javascript-using-map-arbitrary-arguments - Just need to flatten them

Comment: @NinaScholz - ok, sorry, you have right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can travel all elements and add it to result.

```js
const as = [1, 2, 3];
const am = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const al = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const b  = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

function m(a, b) {
  const l = Math.max(a.length, b.length);
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if (a[i] !== undefined) {
      result.push(a[i]);
    }
    if (b[i] !== undefined) {
      result.push(b[i]);
    }
  }
  
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

m(as, b); // -> [1,"a",2,"b",3,"c","d","e"] 
m(am, b); // -> [1,"a",2,"b",3,"c",4,"d",5,"e"] 
m(al, b); // -> [1,"a",2,"b",3,"c",4,"d",5,"e",6,7]
```

Answer (score 2):

A very simple is to loop over and check if value exists. If yes, push else continue.

#### Solution 1

```js
function alternateMerge(a1, a2) {
  var length = Math.max(a1.length, a2.length);
  var output = [];
  for(var i = 0; i< length; i++) {
    if (!!a1[i]) {
      output.push(a1[i])
    }
    if (!!a2[i]) {
      output.push(a2[i])
    }
  }
  return output;
}

var as = [1,2,3];
var am = [1,2,3,4,5];
var al = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var b  = ["a","b","c","d","e"];

console.log(alternateMerge(as, b).join())
console.log(alternateMerge(am, b).join())
console.log(alternateMerge(al, b).join())
```

#### Solution 2

```js
function alternateMerge(a1, a2) {
  const arr = a1.length > a2.length ? a1 : a2;
  return arr.reduce((acc, _, i) => {
    !!a1[i] && acc.push(a1[i]);
    !!a2[i] && acc.push(a2[i]);
    return acc;
  }, [])
}

var as = [1,2,3];
var am = [1,2,3,4,5];
var al = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var b  = ["a","b","c","d","e"];

console.log(alternateMerge(as, b).join())
console.log(alternateMerge(am, b).join())
console.log(alternateMerge(al, b).join())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#concat` with `spread syntax` to generate the array merged alternatively.

```js
var m = (a,b) => {
  const minLen = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
  return [].concat(...a.slice(0, minLen).map((v,i) => [v, b[i]]), a.slice(minLen, a.length), b.slice(minLen, b.length));
};

var as = [1,2,3];
var am = [1,2,3,4,5];
var al = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var b  = ["a","b","c","d","e"];

console.log(m(as,b)); // -> [1,"a",2,"b",3,"c","d","e"] 
console.log(m(am,b)); // -> [1,"a",2,"b",3,"c",4,"d",5,"e"] 
console.log(m(al,b)); // -> [1,"a",2,"b",3,"c",4,"d",5,"e",6,7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const as = [1,2,3];
const am = [1,2,3,4,5];
const al = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
const b  = ["a","b","c","d","e"];

const m = (a, b) => (a.length > b.length ? a : b)
  .reduce((acc, cur, i) => a[i] && b[i] ? [...acc, a[i], b[i]] : [...acc, cur], []);

console.log(m(as,b)); // -> [1,"a",2,"b",3,"c","d","e"]
console.log(m(am,b)); // -> [1,"a",2,"b",3,"c",4,"d",5,"e"]
console.log(m(al,b)); // -> [1,"a",2,"b",3,"c",4,"d",5,"e",6,7]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: try to run your own code and see the result

Comment: @YongQuan, you right.. Thanks for the comment. Answer updated

Comment: The first log is still not the intended result

Comment: @YongQuan Sorry, You right again.. Code fixed